# How does a bitcoin SPV client knows it didn't miss a block from a full node?

Tags: bitcoin

A bitcoin SPV (Simplified Payment Verification) client doesn't have to trust any full node. It submits a bloom filter to a full node for processing only a small subset of all blocks.

But what if an SPV client connected to a malicious full node, and this malicious full node intended not to send a block to this SPV client, which actually contains a transaction that this SPV client is interested in.

How does an SPV client protect itself that it didn't miss any transaction for its wallet address from a full node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPV node connects to multiple, semi-trusted nodes to prevent this attack. Only a single node needs to be honest.

> First, while the SPV client can not be easily fooled into thinking a transaction is in a block when it is not, the reverse is not true. A full node can simply lie by omission, leading an SPV client to believe a transaction has not occurred. This can be considered a form of Denial of Service. One mitigation strategy is to connect to a number of full nodes, and send the requests to each node. However this can be defeated by network partitioning or Sybil attacks, since identities are essentially free, and can be bandwidth intensive. Care must be taken to ensure the client is not cut off from honest nodes.

From https://bitcoin.org/en/operating-modes-guide#potential-spv-weaknesses